# Magento 2: Incomplete address in sales management

Tags: magento2, magento2.1

I'm using version 2.1.8 of magento and when I get orders with long addresses in the sales administration the field "street" appears cut to 40 characters. 
I have set 3 client address lines by configuration, that works correctly and they are saved in BBDD ok, but when passing the order they are cut.

I have checked that the database field where the address field is saved is 255, so I suppose it will be some configuration. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Type of field street in table "sales_order_address" is varchar(255) and street Address in checkout has 3 lines.
So I think 255 is the total character of 3 lines.

**First solution: Set max length for input field Street Address.**

**magento\app\code\Custom\Checkout\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="Custom_Checkout" type="Custom\Checkout\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Checkout\Block\LayoutProcessor.php**

```
namespace Custom\Checkout\Block;

class LayoutProcessor {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject, array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
                ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
            'label' => __('Street Address'),
            'required' => true,
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 60,
            'type' => 'group',
            'children' => [
                    [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '0',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 50],
                ],
                    [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '1',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => false, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 50],
                ]
            ]
        ];
        return $jsLayout;
    }

}
```

**Second solution: set type of field street in table "sales_order_address" to text**

Goodluck !

Comment: I have tried both methods, but without success.
The first one I have not managed to validate the field, I have uploaded the code and cleared cache, should I do something else?
For the second I have simply changed the type of the field, but keep cutting the address to 40 characters.

Comment: Search in table "sales_order_address" in db. What type of street field?

Comment: Is a VARCHAR(255), it should not be cut to 40 characters.

Comment: But have 3 input address in form, right? 255 is total of 3 input address.